# entity listener calls order

Tags: java, entity-framework, jboss, callback, listeners

I'm reading about entity callbacks and listeners and I came to an explanation that's not very clear in my head:

> When an event is raised, the listeners are executed in this order:
>
> 1 @EntityListeners for a given entity or superclass in the array order
>
> 2 Entity listeners for the superclasses (highest first)
>
> 3 Entity Listeners for the entity
>
> 4 Callbacks of the superclasses (highest first)
>
> 5 Callbacks of the entity

The above text is taken from [here](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Web_Platform/5/html/Hibernate_Entity_Manager_Reference_Guide/ch05s02.html) and it appears in different places on the web but in near identical form.

What's the distinction between 1 & 3? Is 3 meant for listeners defined in the "global" xml files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1 @EntityListener for a given entity

means @PostLoad, @PrePersist, etc. callback methods in the Entity itself

> 3 Entity Listeners for the entity

means the @EntityListener annotations on the Entity class.

If you define "global" orm.xml and set entitylisteners for the entity there, than it will overwrite the annotations on the Entity itself.
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/xml-overriding.html